# PHPExcel Save PDF

Tags: php, pdf, phpexcel

Help me i want to save excel in pdf format 
The code:

```
include_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once ('Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');
include_once ('Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php');
include_once ('Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF.php');

include_once ('Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/PDF/DomPDF.php');


$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
//$rendererLibrary = 'tcPDF5.9';
//$rendererLibrary = 'mPDF5.4';
$rendererLibrary = 'domPDF0.6.0beta3';
$rendererLibraryPath = '/' . $rendererLibrary;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Orari');
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');
$objWriter->setSheetIndex(0);
$objWriter->save('esp.pdf');
```

I want to save in pdf format, but when i try to save i have an error response from phpexcel:
**Fatal error**: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'Unable to load PDF Rendering library' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fserv\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\PDF\DomPDF.php:34 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fserv\esportatore.php(190): include_once() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\fserv\index.php(44): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #2 {main} thrown in **C:\xampp\htdocs\fserv\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\PDF\DomPDF.php** on line **34**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409494/how-to-configure-phpexcel-for-pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need DomPDF for rendering the PDF. Check if you have the DomPDF library, otherwise download and implement it as follow:

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'domPDF0.6.0beta3';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__). 'libs/classes/dompdf' . $rendererLibrary;
```

Comment: DomPDF, mPDF or tcPDF.... all can be used, as long as the renderername and librarypath are configured correctly

Comment: Where need to place this variable **$renderLibraryPath**? Is it passed as parameter somewhere?

Comment: Found the asnwer. It need to call the function setPdfRenderer with these parameters `PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer($rendererName,$rendererLibraryPath);`

Comment: I think the $rendererLibraryPath is missing a "/" before $rendererLibrary