# Error when i wont to save file as PDF using PHPExcel

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, phpexcel

I'm using the PHPExcel library in my project and its work fine when i wont to save files format (xls/xlsx). But I need to save files as a PDF format and i found some examples but none of them is working for me.
here the code which i use to generate file with pdf format

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

ini_set('include_path', ini_get('include_path').';../Classes/');

include 'PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';

    $inputFileName = 'file.xls';

        try {
               $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
               $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
               $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
               die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
        }

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$row = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()+1;

        $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
        $highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 
        $highestColumn = $sheet->getHighestColumn();

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'PDF');

$objSheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('A1', 'test test');

$objWriter->save('test100.pdf');

?>
```

and here what the browser show me

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PHPExcel_Writer_Exception' with message 'PDF Rendering library has not been defined.' in C:\wamp\www\projet\PHPExcel\Classes\PHPExcel\Writer\PDF.php on line 56
```

what did  i do wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21599221/phpexcel-save-pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHPExcel doesn't have a PDF Rendering library built-in as part of the code/distribution. Instead, it allows you to use any of 3 different 3rd party PDF libraries (tcPDF, DomPDF or mPDF).

You have to install that PDF Rendering library separately, and then you need to tell PHPExcel which PDF library you have installed before you can save a file as PDF.

This is explained in the [PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/10-Reading-and-Writing.md#pdf) and shown in the examples like 21pdf.php