# How to set the renderer name and renderer path library file into PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

How can I set the renderer name and renderer path library file into PHPExcel?

I tried to set the renderer path and library file into 01simple-download-pdf.php, but I am getting this error below:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant FILE - assumed 'FILE' in C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\sample\PHPExcel-develop\Examples\01simple-download-pdf.php on line 64
NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values
at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you should choose and install a 3rd party PDF rendering library. Examples are: tcPDF, mPDF, DomPDF.

Next, you have to tell PHPExcel which library you choose and where it is located:

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'dompdf_0-6-0_beta3';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/'. $rendererLibrary;
```

(assuming that you choose DomPDF and folder containing it is `dompdf_0-6-0_beta3`)

You can read more [How to configure phpexcel for pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20409494/how-to-configure-phpexcel-for-pdf)

Comment: i set as you said the renderer library  and renderer library path, It's generate the pdf file but it shows failed to load content while opened the generate the pdf file

Comment: I am using NetBeansIDE  the project name is PHPExcel-develop, inside the project stored  the dompdf folder contains the DOMPDF library file. I using this file to generate the pdf file C:\xampp\htdocs\crm\sample\PHPExcel-develop\Examples\01simple-download-pdf.php

Comment: If using domPDF, consider reading its [Usage](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/Usage) and [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ) documentation. And be aware that this library is not tolerant to poorly-formed HTML input. Also, CSS float is not supported.